# gitlab kubernetes runner cannot connect to the docker daemon

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have configured gitlab runner within kubernetes , which is not able to connect to docker daemon . Showing below error .

> $ docker build --cache-from "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}" -t
>   "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}" .
>
> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running? ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with
>   exit code 1

```
stages:
  - push_to_docker

docker_image:
 image: 'docker:latest'
 services:
  - docker:dind
 stage: push_to_docker
 variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: 'gcr.io/abcd-project/test'
 script:
   - docker build --cache-from "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}" -t "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}" .
   - echo "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY" > key.json
   - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < key.json
   - docker push ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
 only:
   - master
 tags:
   - abcd
```

My **config.toml** file is as below

```
listen_address = "[::]:9252"
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 3
log_level = "info"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runner-gitlab-runner-78c7db94bc-lzv76"
  request_concurrency = 1
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "*********"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    host = ""
    bearer_token_overwrite_allowed = false
    image = "ubuntu:16.04"
    namespace = "gitlab-managed-apps"
    namespace_overwrite_allowed = ""
    privileged = true
    service_account_overwrite_allowed = ""
    pod_annotations_overwrite_allowed = ""
    [runners.kubernetes.pod_security_context]
    [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
```

Checked with configuration as below

```
    image: docker:19.03.1
    services:
    - docker:19.03.1-dind
    variables:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
```

And my .gitlab-ci.yml file after changing the configuration is as below:

```
stages:
  - push_to_docker
  - deploy_into_kubernetes
variables:
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: 'gcr.io/abcd-project/test:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA'
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

docker_image_creation:
 image: docker:19.03.1
 services:
  - docker:19.03.1-dind

 stage: push_to_docker

 script:
   - docker build -t "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}" .
   - echo "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY" > key.json
   - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < key.json
   - docker push ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
 tags:
   - cluster
   - kubernetes
```

but getting bellow error :

> Skipping Git submodules setup $ docker build -t "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}"
>   . time="2019-11-04T08:07:37Z" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC:
>   cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on
>   this host?: dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host"
>   error during connect: Post
>   http://docker:2375/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=l1ce41pzm1p9a4jdhs31z9p64&shmsize=0&t=gcr.io%2Fupbeat-flame-247110%2Fgitlab-runner-poc%3A25b1faa0&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: context canceled

Comment: [This issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1986) goes into it a bit, maybe you can try one of the suggested tips.

Answer (score 5):

use docker19, which automatically configures its host for you:

```
image: docker:19.03.1
services:
- docker:19.03.1-dind
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Comment: Hi Eftat ,

Thanks for your update , but I am getting same issue again , I have used docker:19.03.1 as image & docker:19.03.1-dind as service . but not resolved .

Comment: Oh im sorry, will you try it now?

Comment: My issue got resolved after removing tags entry from yml script , Thanks a lot :)

Comment: actually when I am trying to use my own kubernetes runner , its not working .
Yes tried with DOCKER_HOST too

Comment: seems like it works on specific runners only (explains why it started working after you removed the `tags`). how many runners have you got and how did you configure them? who is tagged `abcd` and how the others are tagged?

Comment: 1. I have configured my specific runner within kubernetes through project Settings --> CI/CD --> Runners --> Install Runner on Kubernetes (abcd is my specific runner tag )

2. While I am removed tags , it automatically taken some of the shared runner to execute the pipeline .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201779/discussion-between-satwik-mukherjee-and-efrat-levitan).